Set as Default Dialer
Is it possible to temporarily set my Kotlin app as the default dialer only while app is in use?
Means when i am on my app, My app should be set as default dialer automatically and as soon as i leave my app the default system phone app become default.

I doubt that it is possible. I think it always requires user interaction to change default dialers
